# StencilJS drag and drop

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, jsx, web-component, stenciljs

I wish to implement a drag and drop between lists such as Angular's cdkdroplist https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#transferring-items-between-lists

How would I best go about implementing this into my Stencil component? Can I use the above referenced drag and drop api in some way, and if so: how? If not, is there another approach i should consider?

I am unsure how i would translate this Angular code into my Stencil syntax:

```html
<div
  cdkDropList
  #todoList="cdkDropList"
  [cdkDropListData]="todo"
  [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]"
  class="example-list"
  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much simpler to use [sortablejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sortablejs). You will need the following.

```
npm i sortablejs @types/sortablejs
```

Then construct two `ul` lists with similar to the following:

```
<ul>
    {
        this.items.map(i =>
            <li data-id={i.id}>{i.text}</li>
        )
    }
</ul>
```

See more instructions/exampls on [their page](http://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/).